# Consulta Linq. Orderby

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Buen día, estoy comenzando a usar linq y cuando ejecuto mi consulta. Esta tarda hasta 1 hora. Alguien sabe como puedo optimizarla?

```
if (db.GpsInfo.Any(i => i.device_id == id))
            {
                var gpsinf = db.GpsInfo
                    .Where(i => i.device_id == id)
                    .OrderByDescending(i => i.date)
                    .Select(d => new Types.GpsInfoRequest
                    {
                        device_id = d.device_id,
                        date = d.date,
                        longitude = d.longitude,
                        latitude = d.latitude,
                        speed = d.speed
                    })
                    .Take(last)
                    .ToList();
                    return gpsinf;                
            }return new List<GpsInfoRequest>();
```

Comment: Es muy dificil que podamos ayudarte. No conocemos que estructuras de datos estas usando, ni la cantidad de registros,etc...

Comment: Es la unión de dos tablas, la cantidad de registros es de 3 millones. 
@Pikoh

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `last`?

Comment: Lo unico que puedo recomendarte es que vayas analizando tu consulta parte por parte y viendo donde puedes tener el cuello de botella. Por ejemplo, empiezad por `var gpsinf = db.GpsInfo
                    .Where(i => i.device_id == id)` y miras cuanto tarda. Y así vas añadiendo partes hasta ver por qué tarda tanto. 3 millones de registros son bastantes de todas maneras, probablemente deberías hacer esa consulta o al menos parte de ella en el servidor en lugar de en memoria

Comment: ¿Que es lo que tarda más, la consulta del if o la consulta interna? Te recomiendo que separes el contexto de base de datos a listas de tus modelos, eso para aligerar la arga de consulta.

Comment: Mejor dicho, definitivamente haz el `Take` antes del `Select`. No tiene sentido construir un montón de objetos que no vas a usar.

Comment: Para optimizar tienes varias opciones. Puedes aplicar `Compiled Queries` o también `Query Plan Caching` . También entra en juego optimizar la tabla, como aplicar un índice por fecha y  device_id. Obtén la consulta generada por `linq` y revisa el plan de ejecución de la misma.

Comment: Gracias a todos, estuve leyendo un poco de la documentación de LINQ y al parecer al usar ORDER BY ASC or DESC también se debe usar el metodo SKIP. Esto para optimizar y extraer la información de la manera correcta.

Comment: Puedes poner tu solución para que otros compañeros puedan aprovecharse de ella? Gracias!